# Using custom FileInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How to create custom FileInputFormat that sends file as a single record to the mapper
Please help me with an example using custom FileInputFormat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to use a custom file input format with the following override:

```
        @Override
        protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
            return false;
        }
```

There is an example of this in the hadoop source code, [MultiFileWordCount](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.19/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/MultiFileWordCount.java). In that example, you'd add the above overridden "isSplitable" method to "CustomInputFormat" to avoid splits.

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/pcsanwald/423681e1432168a897fe) of how to incorporate "isSplitable" into the MultiFileWordCount example; using the vanilla hadoop api.